# obtaining proxy from PAC proxy requiring authentication

Tags: winapi, proxy, winhttp, pac

I am attempting to use `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` where the PAC file specified by `WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_OPTIONS.lpszAutoConfigUrl` requires HTTP basic authentication to access.

Is there some way to cause the regular authentication dialog to popup or to supply username and password to use for the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic credential dialog handling is only supported in [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In WinHTTP you have to provide a way to get the user's username and password yourself and pass it to `WinHttpSetCredentials` or similar function. I would check for a return value of `ERROR_WINHTTP_LOGIN_FAILURE` from `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` and then ask for the user's credentials. At which point you could try either of the following to pass those credentials to WinHTTP:

1. Use `WinHttpSetOption` with `WINHTTP_OPTION_USERNAME` and `WINHTTP_OPTION_PASSWORD` to set the username and password and recall `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl`.
2. Or recall `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` and supply the `lpszAutoConfigUrl` parameter with a URL that contains the credentials. (ie `http://user:pass@intranet/`).

If you weren't using basic authentication I would suggest looking at  `fAutoLogonIfChallenged`, but that is of no use to you.